# How can I extract a varying number of groups of digits from a Perl string?

Tags: regex, perl, multiple-matches

I am attempting to parse a string in Perl with the format:

`Messages pushed to the Order Book queues 123691 121574 146343 103046 161253`

I want to access the numbers at the end of the string so intend to do a match like

`/(\d+)/s`

My issue is that the number of values at the end contain a variable number of strings.

What is the best way to format the regexp to be able to access each of those numbers individually?  I'm a C++ developer and am just learning Perl, so am trying to find the cleanest Perl way to accomplish this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: \d does not match [0-9] in Perl 5.8 and 5.10; it matches any UNICODE character that has the digit attribute (including "\x{1815}", MONGOLIAN DIGIT FIVE).  If you mean [0-9] you must either use [0-9] or use the bytes pragma (but it turns all strings in 1 byte characters and is normally not what you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the /g flag to make the match operator perform a global match. In list context, the match operator returns all of the results as a list:

```
@result = $string =~ /(\d+)/g;
```

This works if there are no other numbers than the trailing ones.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the match operator in a list context with the global flag to get a list of all your parenthetical captures. Example:

```
@list = ($string =~ /(\d+)/g);
```

Your list should now have the all the digit groups in your string.
See the documentation on the [match operator](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlop.html#Regexp%5FQuote%5FLike%5FOperators) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

"In scalar context, each execution of m//g finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match" --(From `perldoc perlop`)

So you should be able to make a global regex loop, like so:

```
while ($string =~ /(\d+)/g) {
    push @queuelist, $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
my @numbers;
if (m/Messages pushed to the Order Book queues ([\d\s]+)/) {
   @numbers = split(/\s+/, $1);
}
```

No need to cram it into one regex.

Comment: There are many more elegant ways of doing this, see the other answers.